# Running any meteor command gives error "hasStacks = !!e.stack; RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: meteor

So I am having this issue for the past 8-9 hours. I have been trying to resolve it by googling around.

This is what I have tried so far.
1) Totally uninstalled node and npm. 
2) Totally uninstalled meteor. Deleted all the local/.meteor data. Searched for meteor in entire C drive and deleted it. Restarted the PC.
3) Reinstalled node, npm and meteor js again. (Did steps 1-3 in safe mode also and tried 3 times.)
4) Ran command and got this error again. "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:70
    hasStacks = !!e.stack;
                   ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Note: The same code works for me in another system, so apparently code is fine the issue is with meteor and my pc.

Then I found that creating new windows account and installing meteor there can make it work. So I tried to do that as well but no luck.

I need help to resolve this as I don't have any clue what to do next.

Meteor version is: 1.4
Node version is: 6.10.3
NPM version is: 3.10.10

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for late response, just had the same problem and was eventually able to solve it. The problem is that windows doesn't like long file paths. Unfortunately, meteor is full of them so the installer seems to miss those files.

**Try this:**

- Install meteor if its not already.
- navigate to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local` and delete the
  .Meteor folder.
- Download the installation archive:
  https://meteorinstall-4168.kxcdn.com/packages-bootstrap/1.5/meteor-bootstrap-os.windows.x86_32.tar.gz
- use 7-zip to extract the .Meteor folder somewhere with a shorter
  path; ie: C drive root directory. Make sure you are running 7-Zip as
  admin, and extract it using 7-Zips interface. Don't drag and drop as
  this will extract to the temp folder first.
- Go to your Environment Variables (in Control Panel/Advanced System
  Settings), edit Path, and change the .Meteor directory to where you extracted the folder.
- Open up CMD, cross your fingers, and enter `meteor --version`

Hope this helps any desperate souls out there.